# Iterate Over Static Array of Objects

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, foreach, callbyname

I want to iterate over several ComboBox objects in the same Worksheet `sht`:

```
Dim obj As ComboBox
Dim sht as Worksheet
...
For Each obj In Array(sht.ComboBox1, sht.ComboBox2)
Next obj
```

> **Runtime error 424: object required**   *(raised at `For Each ...`)*

I also tried to address the objects by iterating over the names:

```
Dim s as Variant
Dim obj As ComboBox
Dim sht as Worksheet
...
For Each s In Array("ComboBox1", "ComboBox2")
    obj = CallByName(sht, s, VbGet)
Next s
```

> **Runtime error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set.** *(raised at `obj = ...`)*

1. What is the correct way?
2. And why don't these approaches work as I would expect them to?

Comment: Try it with 'Dim obj as Variant'

Comment: @KostasK. your first idea worked actually, thank :) While playing around, I also found a 2nd solution posted below

Comment: I don't use CallByName a lot, so I wasn't sure if it will return the object. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: I think part of the reason it's not working may have something to do with implicit let-coercion of the objects' *default property* (`.Value`); errors 424 and 91 both support this. Try declaring a local object variable and set it to sht.ComboBox1, then use these variables to make the inline array: because of let-coercion mechanism, using sht.ComboBox1 directly is ambiguous: it reads like it refers to the object, but actually refers to one of its properties' value.

Answer (score 1):

### Approach 1

Prepending `Set` as suggested by @KostasK. to the assignment works:

```
Dim s as Variant
Dim obj As ComboBox
Dim sht as Worksheet
...
For Each s In Array("ComboBox1", "ComboBox2")
    Set obj = CallByName(sht, s, VbGet)
Next s
```

### Approach 2

The ComboBox is part of `Worksheet.OLEObjects`. In this case `obj` must be declared as type `OLEObject` to work (as long as `Option Explicit` is set)

```
Dim s as Variant
Dim obj As OLEObject
Dim sht as Worksheet
...
For Each s In Array("ComboBox1", "ComboBox2")
    Set obj = sht.OLEObjects(s)
Next s
```